# Replace string with another string at a specified index

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0

I trying to replace some part of a string in C#.

E.g. I have a string formatted like this:

```
"We $1 what we $2"
```

(with $1 and $2 are the 2 indexes that have to be replaced).

And a string array:

```
new string[] { "know", "do" };
```

So how do I replace the "$1" with "know", and the "$2" with "do"?

Comment: Probably `string.Replace` is what you are looking for ?

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title. Marking an answer as accepted will tell others that the question is now solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string replaceList = new string[] { "know", "do" };
string Str = "We $1 what we $2";
for(int i = 1; i <= replaceList; i++){
     Str = Str.Replace("$" + i.ToString(), replaceList[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: Take care with 10+ arguments though.

Comment: @Caramiriel why should it have problem with 10+ arguments?

Comment: Nice one, you've made my day!

Comment: @DuyLuân glad I could help

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani If you would have $1=foo, $10=bar, then if you'd replace "$10 $1", you'd end up with "foo0 foo".

Answer (score 0):

if can use something like this :

```
string[] replaceList = new string[] { "know", "do" };
string str = string.Format("We {0} what we {1}", replaceList);
```

It will replace the {} pattern by the value of the array.

Comment: `"We $1 what we $2"` != `"We {0} what we {1}"`

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference @BWA ?

Comment: $1 is not {1}. Little bit different.

Comment: $1 = {0} and $2 = {1}. it should work if the replacementWord in the array is correctly ordered

Comment: He has $1 in string not {1}

Comment: I understand. You mean that maybe he doesn't control the string format. If so yes he could not use string.format